# Error: (typescript) Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am a beginner in Angular 2. I was trying some tutorial via coding in visual studio. I installed npm, nodejs and angular/cli. As I was running through some examples on visual studio code on typescript, I encountered error when I tried to javascript word 'this'

[image: picture of the code]

The error only occurs when I use the javascript word 'this', other than that, it doesnt have error. Any solution for this? Thank you.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  name:string = 'John Doe';
  age:number = 50;
  email:string = 'someone@example.com';
  address: {
    street:string,
    city:string,
    postalcode:number
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor . .. ');
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngonit . . . ');
  }
  public.address = {
    street:'adsadsasd',
    city: 'asdsad',
    postalcode: 123132
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code inline, rather than as an image.

Comment: Post **code**, not *pictures* of code. More: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Remove this.address from your code, this should always be used under funtions of your class, intialize , public address: { city: string, postalCode:string } = { city: 'Vegas', postalCode: '12345'} OR you can use it inside ngOnInit()

Comment: sorry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `this.address={..}` within a function.

You can wrap it into `ngOnInit` function.

I suggest you to create a model in a separate class.

```
export class AddressModel{
     constructor(public street:string='', public city:string='', public postalcode:number=0);
}
```

and initialize it in your `component.ts`.

```
address:AddressModel= new AddressModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The error only occurs when I use the javascript word 'this', other than that, it doesnt have error. Any solution for this? Thank you.

Don't use it. In TypeScript you are encouraged to write members this way:

```
public address: {...} = {...};
```

Where `public` is optional.

For instance, in your class you could have:

```
public address: {
  street:string,
  city:string,
  postalcode:number
} = {
  street:'adsadsasd',
  city: 'asdsad',
  postalcode: 123132
}
```

Comment: im curious that why using 'this' will have error in typescript, since typescript is a superset of javascript.

Comment: It is. `class a { this.x = 14 }` gives you the same error in JavaScript.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai you don't. You may, but you may have the code outside any method if you use that syntax, which is TS compliant.

Comment: @lilezek, yes, but if you want to use `this` you have to wrap it. It's like in c# or Java. If you declare it without this it's like you declare a new property, but if you want to access an existing property you should to wrap it within a function.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai thanks. I tried wrapping in the ngonit function and it worked.

Comment: @DevJo, have a look to my answer and you consider it helps you please accepts it in order to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  name:string = 'John Doe';
  age:number = 50;
  email:string = 'someone@example.com';
  address: {
    street:string,
    city:string,
    postalcode:number
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor . .. ');
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngonit . . . ');
    this.address = {
      street:'Chicago',
      city: 'America',
      postalcode: 123132
    };
  }
}
```

This code works for me. I changed by wrapping this.address inside the ngOnIt() function. Thanks guys.